# jquery slidetoggle not working - not getting any errors

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to use jquery to slideToggle an image I have in the footer tag on my page. I don't get any errors, it shows jquery is a source, but nothing happens. Here is the relevant html code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="hidePic">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 padding-top-10em">
        <ul class="no-bullets font-style">
          <li class="flow-left col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12">Find Chats</li>
          <li class="flow-left col-md-2 col-xs-12">Rate Chats</li>
          <li class="flow-left col-md-2 col-xs-12">Become a Bubsta<span class="enlargeText">R</span>!</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer><img id="pic" src="chat.jpg"></footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and here is the js code:

```
$( "#hidePic" ).click(function() {
    $( "#pic" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: Put your code inside document ready handler https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I did as you stated and it still has no effect. The code I used was: $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#hidePic" ).click(function() {
        $( "#pic" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});

Comment: as @Mark suggested, use `e.preventDefault();` since your button is of type `submit` and it will cause a `postback` when you click on it. alternatively you can change your button type to `button`. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2z5u6hqv/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using prevent default on your submit button...and like others said, wrap in a doc ready function (see code below).

Something like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $( "#hidePic" ).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $( "#pic" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
          // Animation complete.
      });
  });
});
</script>
```